# Browser automation for scraping: Impossible pages due to dropdown/autocomplete input boxes?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape flight data for a thesis project. Specifically from [STA Travel](http://www.statravel.ch/). I don't have much experience, but I have done small similar tasks in the past with other pages and never had issues. But something (many things?) in the making of this page makes the task seemingly impossible.

What I have tried so far:

- Python and Selenium with either Chrome, Geckodriver (Mozilla) and PhantomJS
- Javascript with CasperJS and PhantomJS

With CasperJS and Phantom JS I could not even get the fist textbox filled using the short and seemingly straight forward code given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45138374/impossible-to-sendkeys-with-casperjs-on-some-sites).

With Python and Selenium I get somewhat further but, as far as I see the main reason it all fails is due to the implementation of the input boxes. As soon as you type something in them, a dynamic dropdown menu opens that suggest autocomplete-results. If you don't click one of them properly and just click away from the box after typing, the box auto-clears its text. These things feel like the programming equivalent of oiled soap - no matter how you try to grip them, they will slip out of your control.

To demonstrate, here is some simple runnable code (given you got Python, Selenium and geckodriver installed).

```
# import selenium driver and helpers
from selenium import webdriver

# set browser driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# open url
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

# select forms
depart_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".flight_depart_location.ui-autocomplete-input")
destin_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".flight_arrive_location.ui-autocomplete-input")

# send text
depart_input.send_keys(u"Zürich, Schweiz, ZRH")
destin_input.send_keys(u"Peking Int'l Apt, China, PEK")
```

You will see, the first input gets deleted again as soon as the second is filled in. I have tried all the tricks I could find online, like setting the active element by clicking on it, just sending Keys.ENTER/RETURN to move from box to box. But this site seems "unautomatable" to me. And I am sure the solution is perhaps not that hard, but I cannot find it myself. So if anyone has an idea how to automate and scrape this page, I would be incredibly thankful. No matter how the solution looks (Python, Javascript... something else).

Thank you!

Comment: why dont you click the first dropdown option that comes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to type enough of the location to get the dropdown to appear with the desired location. Then you can look for an `A` tag that contains the desired location and click it. You do that for both the arrival and departure areas. Anything like this that you are likely to reuse you should put into a function.

Since you asked for this in any language, I'll give it to you in Java. You should be able to pretty easily translate it into python.

The functions

```
public static void setArrival(String arrival)
{
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".flight_arrive_location.ui-autocomplete-input")).sendKeys(arrival);
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'" + arrival + "')]"))).click();
}

public static void setDeparture(String departure)
{
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".flight_depart_location.ui-autocomplete-input")).sendKeys(departure);
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'" + departure + "')]")))
            .click();
}
```

The script

```
String arrivalLocation = "Peking";
String departureLocation = "Zürich";
setDeparture(departureLocation);
setArrival(arrivalLocation);
```

Comment: That is awesome, thank you Jeff, that worked beautifully!